# How many positive integers have less than $90000$ have the sum of their digits equal to $17$?

Tags: combinatorics

How many positive integers have less than $90000$ have the sum of their digits equal to $17$?

I tried to write the number as $ABCDE$ and use some math with that (so we need $A + B + C + D + E = 17$), and I tried to use stars and bars, but I got no progress.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: $4,170$. ${}{}{}$

Comment: How did you get that?

Comment: 4 lines of Python.

Comment: Sorry, 5 if you include the print statement.

Comment: @copper.hat wow i feel lied to.

Comment: @DonThousand: I can't help it, I am an inveterate liar...

Comment: Asked and answered on this website multiple times. Try looking at the list of "related".

Comment: One line Mathematica `Select[Range[90000], (Total[IntegerDigits[#]] == 17) &] // Length`

Comment: One line Julia `count(sum.(digits.(1:90000)) .== 17)`

Comment: One line SageMath `len(filter(lambda i:sum(i.digits())==17, (1..90001)))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to find the number of solutions of $$A+B+C+D+E=17$$
where $0\leq A\leq 8$ and all other variables lie between $0$ and $9$. Check that it is coefficient of $x^{17}$ in the following expression:
$$(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7+x^8)$$
$$\times(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7+x^8+x^9)^4$$

Now, apply GP formula and simplify, i.e.
$$Expression = \frac{1-x^9}{1-x}\times\Big(\frac{1-x^{10}}{1-x}\Big)^4$$
$$ = \frac{(1-x^9)(1-x^{10})^4}{(1-x)^5}$$
Now, apply binomial expansion in $(1-x^{10})^4$ and ignore terms which don't contribute to term of $x^{17}$, we get,

$$\frac{(1-x^9)(1-4x^{10})}{(1-x)^5}$$
Now, you have terms with powers of $x$ as $0,9\&10$ in numerator, find the coefficients of $x^{17}, x^8\& x^7$ in the power series expansion of denominator using formula and you are done.

Hope it helps:)

Comment: What is "GP" supposed to mean here?

Comment: Geometric Progression

Answer (score 1):

Stars and bars sounds like a good idea.  You want to put $17$ balls in $5$ buckets, with no more than $9$ balls in any one bucket.  First do it without the $9$-ball restriction.  Now you have to subtract the number of ways that have $10$ or more balls in a bucket.  Since there are only $17$ balls, there can't be more than one bucket with $10$ balls.  Choose a bucket in which to place $10$ balls.  Now distribute the remaining $7$ balls in the $5$ buckets.

**EDIT**
I forgot about "less than $90000.$"  You also have to subtract the cases where there are exactly $9$ balls in the first bucket, so $8$ in the remaining $4$.

Comment: I got ${23 \choose 17} - {13\choose 7}$, which doesn't match up with @copper.hat's Python program

Comment: First, you have the stars and bars formula wrong.  You should have $\binom{21}{17}$ and $\binom{11}{7}$.  Second, you ignored the fact that there are $5$ ways to choose the bucket with $10$ balls.

Comment: Don't we only have to consider the case in which there's $9$ balls in the one bucket, and $8$ in the remaining $4$? How can we have $10$ balls in each bucket since $0 \leq A, B, C, D, E \leq 9$?

Comment: @hom That's right, you cannot have 10 or more balls in a bucket and this is what saulpatz suggests: you have to **subtract** these cases from your initial count. I checked the numbers with this method and indeed you get $4170$ as the result.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just hard to put in a comment. Python code.

```
c = 0
for i in range(1,90000):
    if sum(map(int,list(str(i))))==17:
        c += 1
print c
```

Comment: A comprehension would be shorter but less comprehensible.

Comment: Perhaps a little counter-intuitive to expected behavior but Strings are iterables in python so map will apply the function to each character of the string automatically without your list conversion. E.g. sum(map(int,str(11))) returns 2, not 11 as one may reasonably expect. So the a code golf-ed version of this could be:

Comment: sum(1 for i in range(90000) if sum(map(int,str(i))) == 17)

Comment: @RagibZaman: The goal was readability not code golf :-).